# How to use UIImagePickerController 's CameraOverlayView property in Simulator environment

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I was working on creating a custom Camera Overlay and setting it to UIImagePickerController's CameraOverlayView property.

However since I am not enrolled in to Apple's developer program I can not really deploy and test the application package on actual device.

I also debugged my code and it appears that on Simulator you can not really choose and set **imagePicker.sourceType** property to the **UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera**. Because camera functionality is not available on simulator.

**Am I right in my thinking ?**
Or am I missing something and there is a way to set the CameraOverlayView property and test it on simulator ?

Here is the example of my code:

```
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

// Check what is possible or supported on simulator, otherwise,
//just pick from Photo library

if ( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

if ( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
} else  {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}


// Allow edit
[imagePicker  setEditing:YES animated:YES   ];
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
imagePicker.delegate = self;

// set custom Overlay
//imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = ( not working in simulator )

//Display the imagePicker on the screen

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Apple hasn't let us yet use our MacBooks that have webcams for testing a native camera in the simulator (really dumb honestly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the camera does not work in the iOS simulator.